# Receiver type error Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to make a Hangman game. I realize my methods probably aren't the most efficient. Basically, each time a letter is entered I'm checking to see if there are any empty spaces left so I can display the "You won!" image. I keep getting two errors:

> Receiver type 'char' is not 'id' or interface pointer , consider
>   casting it to 'id'
>
> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x63)

Any help is MUCH appreciated.

```
        BOOL dash = YES;

        for(int j = 0; j < self.correctWord.length; j++){

            char temp = [self.correctWord characterAtIndex:j];

            if([temp isEqual:@"-"])
                dash = YES;

        }

        if(dash == YES)
            self.hangmanImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wonimg"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing with Objective-C is it's a 2-headed beast.

1. There are objects, to which you send messages.
2. There's plain C. No messages here, just operators and function calls.

Let's examine the error:

> Receiver type 'char' is not 'id' or interface pointer , consider casting it to 'id'

A "receiver" is whatever receives a message. Making a generalization which is no longer accurate, a message is the square bracket stuff:

```
[receiver message]
```

or

```
[receiver messageArgument1:arg1 argument2:arg2]
```

An `id` type is Objective-C's notion of "any object".

So the error is trying to say that the receiver is a `char` which isn't an object. It's a plain C type. Here's the line with the problem:

```
if([temp isEqual:@"-"])
```

For a plain C type, test equality with the `==` operator:

```
if (temp == '-')
```

Comment: All correct except that last line... `temp` may, technically, not be 7 bit ASCII character.   I'd lean to a more pure-ObjC solution and use an NSScanner to detect non-letter characters in the string (or something).

Comment: Yes, `characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar` not a `char`. Another approach would be to take a substring of length 1 instead. Then you'd be dealing with an NSString, which is an object.